# An Issue with SPCascadeDropdowns

Tags: jquery, lookup-column, spservices, cascading

I created Three Lists  :

- Countries {Title}
- Regions {Title,Country(Lookup link with Title of Countries List)} and
- States {State,Region Name(Lookup link with Title of Regions List), Country Name (Lookup link with Title of Countries List)}

In the States List , I added Script Editor Web Part to Newform.aspx , but it didn't filter The Regions Name with Selecting Country Name
this is The Script That Embed With Page :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

     $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({

    relationshipList: "Regions",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Country",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    relationshipListSortColumn: "ID",
    parentColumn: "Country_x0020_Name",
    childColumn: "Region_x0020_Name",
    debug: true
      });
});
```

Comment: `parentColumn` and `childColumn` should be display names, not internal names: `Country Name` and `Region Name`

Comment: Thank You , it worked fine , but i have another issue ,,, when i try to make the Country Name as Require , filtering doesn't work why ?

Comment: Try using the newest version of SPServices: v. 2014.02. According to Marc, the required field issue is fixed in this version: http://sympmarc.com/tag/codeplex/

Comment: another thing , assume that  i have two static countries (USA,CANADA) , Can i do This Filtering Without Creating Country List

Comment: Not using SPCascadeDropdowns. It would be possible with JSOM, but I don't think it would be worth the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parentColumn` and `childColumn` should be display names, not internal names: `Country Name` and `Region Name`